# Proof of Cartan's classification theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, complex-geometry

I am trying to understand *E. Cartan’s classification of 3–dimensional homogeneous strongly pseudoconvex CR-manifolds* given in the papers

*Sur la géométrie pseudo-conforme des hypersurfaces de l'espace de deux variables complexes (I) & (II).*

These papers are in french in which I have $0$ knowledge.

Can anyone suggest some reference where I can find the proofs written in English?

Thank you.